# jQuery detect filled input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html code:

```
<label for="input">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

I wanted to make script that hides label if input has anything filled in it. I made this, but it doesn't do anything. Why?

```
if ($("input").val().length !== 0) {
    $(this).siblings().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't refer to that input field when using $(this).sibl... 
(`this` by default is `Window` )
as it is not wrapped around a function or anything. 
Refer to it in the second line as `$('#input').siblings().hide()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an .each function to look at the input and hide the label if it's empty using the following:

```
$("#input").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).siblings().hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Karolina Ticha it does work in the codepen link you provided. As you can see the label "Name" is hidden.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `<input type="text" id="input"/>` for `$("input").val()` but it's missing '#' for id selector as `$("#input").val()`

Comment: that's not a problem. html elements can be accessed by their tag name as well.

Comment: yes you are right, the problem causing here with is, using of $(this). thanx for pointing it